# Can I change the background image in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

[Visual Studio editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkAeH.png)

like this(above link), but this is in Visual Studio,

I found a plugin 'BackgroundImage', but it doesn't work.

How can I change the background image in PhpStorm?

Comment: AFAIK -- only that BackgroundImage plugin was offering such functionality -- you contact developer and ask if it can be fixed to work with latest IDE versions.

Comment: yeah, I'm going to try it, thank you.

Comment: I found another plugin, call 'BackgroundChibiChara', but it seems to have some bug.

Comment: I found another plugin again, https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8278, it is wonderful.

Comment: It's a brand new one -- have not seen it there before. If it does what you want -- post your finding as an answer (you can accept your own answers as well) -- it could be useful for other people with the same problem.

Comment: It will make me feel more happy :) and thank you @LazyOne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another plugin again, it is wonderful, it can change editor background image, it can zoom in and fix the position.

plugin name: intellij-wallpaper

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8278

Source code: https://github.com/cocuh/intellij-wallpaper/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a full background image, you can place a smaller image in the upper right hand corner of the PhpStorm window. I created some instructions and some sample images in this [github project](https://github.com/ken-mills/phpstorm-project-markers). The gimp .xcf file is included if you want to change the colors.